# Is it bad practice to access HTML elements by ID in React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I was told at a previous job that I should never access HTML elements directly through means like getElementById in React TypeScript. I'm currently implementing Chart.js. For setting up the chart, I was initially using a useRef hook instead of accessing context, but now it seems like I need to grab the canvas by ID in order to instantiate it properly. I want to know if this is kosher.

I suspect something is wrong with me not using a context, because my chart data doesn't load and throws a console error: "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item"

```
    useEffect(() => {
      chart = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: labelsArray.map((label) => {
          const date = new Date(label);
          // add one because month is 0-indexed
          return date.getUTCMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getUTCDate();
        }),
        datasets: [
          {
            data: valuesArray,
            backgroundColor: "#1565C0",
            borderRadius: 6,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        interaction: { mode: "index" },
        onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
          const target = event.native.target;
          (target as HTMLInputElement).style.cursor = chartElement[0]
            ? "pointer"
            : "default";
        },
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            mode: "index",
            enabled: true,
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Daily Usage Past 30 Days",
            align: "start",
            fullSize: true,
            font: {
              size: 24,
            },
            padding: {
              bottom: 36,
            },
          },
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        elements: {
          line: {
            borderJoinStyle: "round",
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return () => {
      chart.destroy();
    };
  }, [labelsArray, valuesArray]);
```

and HTML:

```
<div className="mt-80 ml-12 p-8 shadow-lg border-2 border-slate-100 rounded-xl items-center">
   <canvas id="chart" ref={chartRef}></canvas>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</div>
```

Also, per the Chart.js documentation: "To create a chart, we need to instantiate the Chart class. To do this, we need to pass in the node, jQuery instance, or 2d context of the canvas of where we want to draw the chart." Not sure how we would do this with a useRef

Comment: Why do you need to grab the canvas by ID? You can have a ref that points to it.

Comment: Please be a bit more concrete here. What makes you think you need to grab the canvas by ID exactly? Do you have a code example?

Comment: @ggorlen it's because when I use my ref to instantiate the chart, i get the console error: "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item"

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see the code that causes  that error. I can't help with code I can't see. Almost certainly, the solution isn't to just give up and use `getElementById` but to fix the real issue, whatever it is. Sometimes it's appropriate to `getElementById`, but it's a last resort. There's almost certainly a better way.

Comment: @ggorlen i added code snippets

Comment: Try adding a `if (chartRef.current != null)` check before initializing. And add `chartRef` to the dependency array of `useEffect`.

Comment: @Nat can you show your full component and package.json? There's still a lot left to the imagination here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,
It is not good practice to access `dom` elements directly through `document API`.

Because in react

1. `virtual dom` is **responsible** for painting/ **re-rendering** the UI.
2. ***State updation*** is the proper way to tell react to trigger re-render.
3. The flow is state updation -> calculate differences -> find who over is using that state -> grab those `components` -> re-render only those components.
4. `virtual dom` is the **source of truth** for react to render and update actual `DOM`.

Now, If you directly access some dom elements and do some operation on it, like updating, react will never know that some change has happened and it will basically break the flow of the react, in which case there will be no reason to use `react.js`

The flow would be accessing some dom element -> updating -> displaying.

The problem with this approach if react encounters that later what i have in virtual dom is not actual presentation in the actual dom, which will create mess.
That is the reason there is `useRef` hook to [manipulate dom.](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)

Comment: This is nice to know but OP now has some concrete code. They probably know they shouldn't manipulate the DOM directly but thought they had to for ChartJS purposes, so answers should now address the situation at hand rather than OP's [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: You question: Is it bad practice to access HTML elements by ID in React TypeScript? Didn't my answer, answer to your question?

Comment: It's not my question. OP asked that, but they really meant to ask "how can I use ChartJS in a React component without accessing the DOM directly?" after discussion in the comments. It's an XY problem (see link above). They tried to `useRef` as they know they should, but it didn't work for some reason, so we're waiting for a [mcve] so we can help.